# How to set tab size for pager used in git diff?

Tags: git, formatting, diff

I use the pager **most**

It's pain to see diff output with tabsize=8. How can I specify tabsize==2 ?

```
@@ -48,6 +49,7 @@
                                                <div class="content_inner">
                                                        <%= yield %>
                                                        <div class="clear"></div>
+              <%= render "emoticons/menu" %>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For a `less` pager, you can update the pager

`git config --global core.pager 'less -x2'`

You can do the same with `most`if this one has an option to change the tab size

Comment: Ok, I'll rather switch to **less**. Thank you, krampstudio!